# Raphael js: how to overlap two rotated rectangle with different origin point

Tags: javascript, matrix, svg, raphael

I have two rectangles with same initial dimension:
r1 = paper.rect(200,100,100,100)
r2 = paper.rect(200,100,100,100)

then rotate:
r1.rotate(45,200,100)

then rotate:
r2.rotate(45) <-- origin: center

the quest:
how to calculate the translation (dx, dy) so that r2 stacked with r1?

r2.translate(dx, dy);

Comment: Can I ask why ? Just wondering if its for an end solution that may not actually need that.

Comment: I actually use raphael, when a rectangle is not rotated and then we scale, it was nice. but when the rectangle is rotated, then we scale, there is a shift from the origin.

Comment: Scale from the center instead ?

Comment: scale from origin (left, top + height / 2)

Comment: ups, it seems my mistake when calculating matrix.

Comment: @Ian thanks for fast response

Comment: No problem, shout/update if you still have a problem.